# Тормозит распознавание речи

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Есть простой код на `python` по распознаванию голоса с использованием библиотеки `speech_recognition`:

```
import speech_recognition

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # инициализация инструментов распознавания и ввода речи
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

    while True:
        # старт записи речи с последующим выводом распознанной речи 
        voice_input = record_and_recognize_audio()
        print(voice_input)
```

Уже на этапе обработки голоса зависает секунд на 10-15...
Как можно повысить скорость работы сервиса? Куда копать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тестировал на разных мощностях разных серверов, но видно, это особенность облачного распознавания от SpeechRecognition.
Перешел на библиотеку Vosk с предобученными моделями Kaldi, и скорость увеличилась раз в десять.